# Spring Data Neo4j 6 @ConvertWith implementation

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to implement a neo4j `@ConvertWith` on a list property.

```
@ConvertWith(converter = "SomeConverter.class") 
List<CustomObject> customObject;
```

I see that the SomeConverter should impl ->

```
implements Neo4jPersistentPropertyConverter<List<CustomObject>>
```

but i cant get the conversion to work.. it always seems to ask for the required id property in the CustomObject

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required identifier property not found for class
```

It might not even go into my converter?

Question: Whats the correct way to implement a converter for a list of objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving it without the @ConvertWith by registering a GenericConverter does work.
So you write a converter for the actual MyCustomClass, to neo4j driver StringValue, instead of writing a conversion for the whole list( List). Because neo4j can convert by itself from a List.
Then there is no need to write @ConvertWith above the property or anything else but what is below.

So the solution then:

```
public class CustomConverter implements GenericConverter 

{
    @Override
    public Object convert(final Object source, final TypeDescriptor sourceType, final TypeDescriptor targetType)
    {
        if (sourceType.getType().equals(StringValue.class))
        {
            System.out.println("reading converted");
            return this.toEntityAttribute((StringValue) source);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("writing converting");
            return this.toGraphProperty((MyCustomClass) source);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Set<ConvertiblePair> getConvertibleTypes()
    {
        Set<ConvertiblePair> convertiblePairs = new HashSet<>();
        convertiblePairs.add(new ConvertiblePair(MyCustomClass.class, Value.class));
        convertiblePairs.add(new ConvertiblePair(Value.class, MyCustomClass.class));
        return convertiblePairs;
    }

    private MyCustomClass toEntityAttribute(final StringValue value)
    {
        MyCustomClass result = null;
        try
        {
            result = AbstractJsonConverter.createObjectFromJson(value.asString(), MyCustomClass.class);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            CustomConverter.log.warn(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        System.out.println("reading result:" + result);
        return result;
    }

    private Value toGraphProperty(final MyCustomClass value)
    {
        String result = null;
        try
        {
            result = AbstractJsonConverter.createJsonFromObject(value);
        }
        catch (RepresenationCreationException e)
        {
            CustomConverter.log.warn(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return Values.value(result);
    }
}
```

And then you have to register the converter by defining a bean.

```
@Bean
public Neo4jConversions neo4jConversions()
{
    Set<GenericConverter> additionalConverters = Collections.singleton(new CustomConverter());
    return new Neo4jConversions(additionalConverters);
}
```